# MPI send recv confusion

Tags: mpi

I have attached a sample of the MPI program I am trying to write. When I run this program using "mpirun -np 4 a.out", my output is:

```
 Sender:            1
 Data received from            1
 Sender:            2
 Data received from            1
 Sender:            2
```

And the run hangs there. I dont understand why does the sender variable change its value after MPI_recv? Any ideas?

Thank you,
Pradeep

`       program  mpi_test

```
    include  'mpif.h'

!----------------( Initialize variables )-------------------- 
  integer, dimension(3) :: recv, send

  integer :: sender, np, rank, ierror

  call  mpi_init( ierror )
  call  mpi_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, rank, ierror )
  call  mpi_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, np, ierror )

!----------------( Main program )-------------------- 

!     receive the data from the other processors
  if (rank.eq.0) then
     do sender = 1, np-1
        print *, "Sender: ", sender
        call mpi_recv(recv, 3, mpi_int, sender, 1,
 &       mpi_comm_world, status, ierror)
        print *, "Data received from ",sender
     end do
  end if

!   send the data to the main processor
  if (rank.ne.0) then
     send(1) = 3
     send(2) = 4
     send(3) = 4
     call mpi_send(send, 3, mpi_int, 0, 1, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
  end if


!----------------( clean up )-------------------- 
  call mpi_finalize(ierror)

  return
  end program mpi_test`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical stack smashing scenario. You have not declared the `status` variable and hence the compiler automatically makes one `REAL` variable for you. But `status` should rather be an `INTEGER` array of `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` elements:

```
integer, dimension(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: status
```

What happens in your case is that `status` is too small to hold the real MPI status object and hence some of the other stack variables get overwritten. Simply declare `status` as it should be declared in order to solve the problem.

Another thing - modern Fortran supports the `IMPLICIT NONE` statement, which disables automatic declaration of undeclared variables. If you put `implicit none` immediately after the `include` statement, the compiler would generate an error message instead.